# Use a character vector to build a new dataframe containing rows in which strings from that vector are found

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to query a `database` using a character vector `query_list`, and return a dataframe `query_output`. In this two-column output dataframe, each row corresponds to a single string from the query vector. First of the two columns in the output dataframe (called `term`) names this string, and the second column (called `enzyme`) lists all rows of the `database` in which the query string was found, defined by the column `enzyme` from the database).

My query and database look as follows:

```
query_list <- c("term(A)", "term(B)", "term(C)", "term(D15)")
database <- data.frame(enzyme = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1")
                       ,term = c("term(A);term(K);term(Y);term(G);term(F);"
                                 ,"term(A);term(K);term(Y);term(G);term(F);"
                                 ,"term(H);term(K);term(Y);term(C);term(F);"
                                 ,"term(H);term(B);term(Y);term(C);term(F);"
                                 ,"term(H);term(K);term(D15);term(G);term(F);"))
```

the database looks like this:

```
  enzyme                                       term
1     A1   term(A);term(K);term(Y);term(G);term(F);
2     B1   term(A);term(K);term(Y);term(G);term(F);
3     C1   term(H);term(K);term(Y);term(C);term(F);
4     D1   term(H);term(B);term(Y);term(C);term(F);
5     E1   term(H);term(K);term(D15);term(G);term(F);
```

The resulting dataframe `query_output`:

```
> query_output 
       term  enzyme
1   term(A)  A1, B1
2   term(B)      D1
3   term(C)  C1, D1
4 term(D15)      E1
```

Optimally, the solution would be pipeable, and not a loop (although anything will be appreciated). I don't say what I have tried because I don't really know how to go about it in a concise way.

Comment: some places it says `herm` and not `term`, is that intentional?

Comment: @Mossa No, thank you for pointing this out, this is now corrected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `separate_rows()` from `tidyr` package you can separate the values in `term`. Then, just filter by your `query_list`, group by `term` and use `paste0(..., collapse=';')` to collapse all values for each `term` in the same row.

```
database %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(term,sep=";") %>% 
  filter(term %in% query_list) %>%
  group_by(term) %>% 
  summarise(enzyme = paste0(enzyme,collapse=', '))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  term      enzyme
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 term(A)   A1, B1 
2 term(B)   D1    
3 term(C)   C1, D1 
4 term(D15) E1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)
database %>%
  mutate(term = sub(";$", "", term)) %>%
  separate_rows(term, sep = ";") %>%
  filter(term %in% query_list) %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  summarise(enzyme = toString(enzyme))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  term      enzyme
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 term(A)   A1, B1
2 term(B)   D1    
3 term(C)   C1, D1
4 term(D15) E1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your database to your desired format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

transformed_database <- database %>%
  separate_rows(term, sep = ';') %>%
  filter(term != '') %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  summarise(enzyme = paste0(enzyme, collapse = ', '))

transformed_database
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>   term      enzyme            
#>   <chr>     <chr>             
#> 1 term(A)   A1, B1            
#> 2 term(B)   D1                
#> 3 term(C)   C1, D1            
#> 4 term(D15) E1                
#> 5 term(F)   A1, B1, C1, D1, E1
#> 6 term(G)   A1, B1, E1        
#> 7 term(H)   C1, D1, E1        
#> 8 term(K)   A1, B1, C1, E1    
#> 9 term(Y)   A1, B1, C1, D1
```

Then, querying it is as simple as

```
transformed_database %>%
  filter(term %in% query_list)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   term      enzyme
#>   <chr>     <chr> 
#> 1 term(A)   A1, B1
#> 2 term(B)   D1    
#> 3 term(C)   C1, D1
#> 4 term(D15) E1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate through the `query_list` in base R, and use `enframe` from `tibble` to make it a dataframe.

```
library(tibble)

enframe(sapply(query_list, function(x)
  paste(database[grepl(x, strsplit(database$term, ";"), fixed = T), 1], collapse = ", ")),
  name = "term",
  value = "enzyme")

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  term      enzyme
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 term(A)   A1, B1
2 term(B)   D1    
3 term(C)   C1, D1
4 term(D15) E1
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```r
database %>% 
  separate_rows(term, sep = ";") %>% 
  filter(term != "") %>%
  filter(term %in% query_list) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  group_by(term) %>% 
  summarise(enzyme = str_c(enzyme, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Which results in

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  term      enzyme
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 term(A)   A1, B1
2 term(B)   D1    
3 term(C)   C1, D1
4 term(D15) E1
```